# Why doesn't Haskell Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 have an unzip function?

Tags: haskell, text-processing

I want to remove trailing characters 'T' from a string, and at the same time shorten an associated string by the same number of characters that are removed from the first string.

I tried as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as C
zipTrim s q
    | C.null s = (C.empty, C.empty)
    | C.head (last $ C.group s) == 'T' =
        unzip (C.zip (C.concat $ init $ C.group s) q)
    | otherwise = (s, q)
```

However, the `unzip` returns me a pair of `[Char]` instead of a pair of `Bytestring`.

The non-lazy version has an unzip function that returns a pair of `Bytestring`:
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.1/docs/Data-ByteString-Char8.html#v:unzip

**Why isn't there a similar function for the lazy version?**

(Feel free to suggest better solutions to my co-trimming problem. I would like to have something not too slow.)

Comment: Perhaps because it wouldn't be very clear how lazy the lazy bytestring was. You can just convert your strict bytestrings to lazy bytestrings.

Comment: Probably no good reason; I would guess someone forgot. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.1/docs/src/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html#unzip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance, `unzip` for lazy bytestrings boils down to using `pack` on both halves of a pair of "byte" lists:

```
import Data.Bifunctor
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as C

unzipLazy :: [(Char, Char)] -> (C.ByteString, C.ByteString)
unzipLazy = bimap C.pack C.pack . unzip
```

That can catch you off guard, though -- as Reid Barton notes, "[it isn't] very clear how lazy the lazy bytestring [is]". For instance, this...

```
print . fst . unzipLazy $ repeat ('a', 'b')
```

... doesn't run in constant memory. (By the way, the same happens with the existing [`Data.ByteString.Lazy.unzip`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.1/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html#g:21) that jberryman mentions.)

P.S.: In any case, I'm not sure if lazy bytestrings actually gain you much in this situation, as `last . C.group` brings the whole first bytestring into memory from the outset.